# Use Command X on macOS Finder

Tags: macos, plugins, finder

Is there an app or plugin that will allow me to use command x to cut files in macOS finder. I can't live with command shift v.

Thanks!

There has to be a software or plugin that does it right. I can't find anything off google.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for questions about programming, not general computer usage; [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) is a better place to ask about things like this. But I doubt you'll find anything, because on macOS the convention is that when you cut something it's removed immediately (moved into the pasteboard), it doesn't stay until you paste it somewhere else. If you *don't* paste it, it just vanishes (i.e. just stays removed), and accidentally vanishing files because you didn't remember to paste them would be bad.

Answer (score 0):

Here is it! Simple and nice little app
https://sindresorhus.com/command-x
https://apps.apple.com/ru/app/command-x/id6448461551?l=en&mt=12